# Is it possible to do a custom rendering with highchart-ng?!

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I tried to use Highcharts [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) to create my own custom shapes.
Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to invoke those `methods`.

Is it even possible to use Highcharts `methods`? with `highcharts-ng`?!

**[My Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/yk56WXvF3TLFlGJwIIUo?p=preview)**

**My code:**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.chartDonut = {
    options: {
      chart: {
          type: 'pie',

      },
      colors: [
           '#FFFFFF', 
           '#AA4643', 

      ],
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },

      legend: {
        borderWidth: 0
      },

      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          borderWidth: 0.2,
          borderColor: '#000000',
        }
      }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
    },

    backgroundColor: '#cccccc',
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y +' %';
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Browsers',
        data: [{
              name: 'MATCHED',
                y: 25
            }, {
                name: 'UNMATCHED',
                y: 50,

          color: {
              pattern: 'http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/pattern1.png',
              width: 6,
              height: 6
          }

            }],

        size: '60%',
        innerSize: '56%',
        showInLegend: false,
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          connectorWidth: 0,
          connectorPadding: 0,
          useHTML: true,
          x: 20,
          formatter: function() {
              if (this.point.name === 'UNMATCHED') 
                return '<div id="donut_unmatched">'  
                        + '<div id="unmatched_num">' + this.y + '</div>' 
                        + '<div id="unmatched_txt">' + this.point.name + '</div>'
                        + '</div>';
          }
        }
    }]
  };
});
```

Comment: I advice to contact with the author of this wrapper, because it seems that not all Highcahrts functions are available there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author here. At the moment it is not possible to do this. Pull requests gladly accepted. I'll probably add it myself in the near future.

See here to track changes: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/issues/97

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with current version, while documentation is not clear.
In source code, highcharts constructor is called:

```
new Highcharts.Chart(mergedOptions, func)
```

The second parameter is a callback when highcharts initialization is finished:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.Chart (it does not explain its arguments)
We can get the chart object from the 1st argument of this function. Add following code to your chart config object:

```
func: function(chart) {
  $scope.chartObj = chart;
}
```

Then you can use it in your view or code (for any API calls):

```
<span>{{chartObj.renderer.height}}</span>
```

```js
$scope.chartObj.renderer.circle(...);
$scope.chartObj.getSelectedPoints();
```

As an example I forked the original plunk here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6WvHEjJfr4pGqd2OvPKF?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

i can't find the answer either,but i've got a resolution, which is invoke the renderer in the formatter of xAxis label formatter function, and it works..